# Word for a sheet of paper that tells you what to measure

Tags: single-word-requests

I work in a laboratory environment where the experts measure various parameters of food, water, soil, etc. Before they do the measurement itself they print a sheet of paper on which they can read which parameters they should measure on which samples. How would you call this paper?

EDIT:
Thank you for your suggestions.

These are the words we considered already: datasheet (it isn't too descriptive as we have other sheets with data), measuring sheet (it's a mirror translation from how we call this sheet in our language).

Example usage:
I want to print the *"sheet"* for these measurements, so I know what machines I have to prepare.
I fill out the *"sheet"* with the results of the measurements.

Comment: Please add more details of your exact requirement and also on what research you have done so far, including any current terms you use or have in mind. An example sentence where you would like to use this word will also help.

Comment: Seems to me like you're talking about a "list of required measurements".

Comment: In military parlance, this is a *tasking*. I'm not sure what a civilian lab would use, though.  It probably depends on how much intelligence is embodied in the list. If it is just a menu of all options with some boxes ticked, it is an order sheet. If an AI or scheduler has prepared it to optimize the work flow, I'd call it a test schedule. It can also just be called a *job* or [*work order*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Work_order).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would simply go with a form:

> *5 form:* A printed document with blank spaces for information to be inserted:
>
> an application form -[ODO](https://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/form)

As you can see in the dictionary example it's modified by a noun adjunct. Thus, you could use a **measurement form** or a **parameter form**.

Answer (score 1):

You are most likely referring to a ***checklist***.

From **[ODO](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/checklist)**:

> **checklist**
> *NOUN*
>
> A list of items required, things to be done, or points to be
> considered, used as a reminder.
>
> **Example sentences**:
>
> We did not present our groups with a checklist of
> topics or require them to come to consensus.
>
> All delegates will be given sample policies, case reviews and record
> keeping checklists which they can use in their own organisations.
>
> And now they have to go through the whole series of checklists that
> are involved in the countdown.

Comment: Thank you, checklist is almost perfect. I forgot to mention in my original question that they write the results on this paper after the measurement is done.

Answer (score 0):

I think you may refer to it as a  ***[table:](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/table)***

> - An orderly arrangement of data, especially one in which the data are arranged in columns and rows in an essentially rectangular form.

(The Free Dictinary)

Comment: That does not seem very specific.

Answer (score 0):

A "**rubric**" is defined by [oxforddictionaries.com](https://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/rubric) as

> A set of instructions or rules.

Rubrics are most often seen in academic settings, included with tests or classwork, describing the procedure by which the work should be performed.

Comment: That's close, but these sheets don't contain exact instructions, to do one measurement they have to use this machine with these settings, on the other measurement they have to use some completely other machine and/or settings, but these informations aren't on the sheets, only the measurements.